# Value changing itself

Tags: c++

I have implemented the next code in C++, but I was not obtaining what I want, then I noted that for any reason, a value in a matrix was changing by itself (the value of R[0][0][0]).
I have the same problem in my system and in Ideone, even with C++14:

```
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int N, K, Mi[9], M[9][17][3], R[9][1001][2], i, j, aux;
    Mi[0]=0;
    for(i=0; i<1001; i++) R[0][i][0]=1, R[0][i][1]=1;

    printf("%d/%d\n",R[0][0][0],R[0][0][1]);
    //R[0][0][0]==1 just like I want

    for(i=1; i<9; i++) R[i][0][0]=0, R[i][0][1]=1;
    for(i=0; i<17; i++) M[i][0][0]=0, M[i][0][1]=1, M[i][0][2]=0;

    printf("%d/%d\n",R[0][0][0],R[0][0][1]);
    //R[0][0][0]==0, why? I don't understand

    while(scanf("%d %d",&N,&K)==2)
    {
        for(i=1; i<=N; i++) scanf("%d",Mi+i);
        for(i=1; i<=N; i++)
        {
            for(j=1; j<=Mi[i]; j++)
            {
                scanf("%d %d %d",&M[i][j][0],&M[i][j][1],&M[i][j][2]);
                M[i][j][0]=M[i][j][1]-M[i][j][0];
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have used in my code `R[0][0][0]=1` for correct it, but it still is strange for me, I don't want to have future problems by anything like this.

If I do some changes in the code (for example, removing the while cycle that is next) the value don't change.

Is it a bug?
Am I doing anything bad?

Comment: `for(i=1; i<9; i++) R[i][0][0]=0` i is never 0

Comment: The third 'for' loop is the problem.  As written, you are indexing off the end of your M array, because 17 > 9.  I think you meant it to be written as `for(i=0; i<17; i++) M[0][i][0]=0, M[0][i][1]=1, M[0][i][2]=0` instead.

Comment: "even with C++14" Nice try, but unfortunately, using newer standards will rarely fix your bugs. =D

Comment: Don't you feel even a little weird writing so many magic numbers with 0 explanation in such a small amount of code? Like.. isn't your skin crawling?

Comment: @mkimball Yes, it was, thankyou so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `M` has dimensions `[9][17][3]`, the loop

```
for(i=0; i<17; i++) M[i][0][0]=0, M[i][0][1]=1, M[i][0][2]=0;
```

modifies non-existent elements.   That is undefined behaviour.   Modifying some other variable (or element of an array) is a feasible outcome.

Comment: Thankyou so much, the code need to be `for(i=0; i<9; i++) M[i][0][0]=0, M[i][0][1]=1, M[i][0][2]=0;`, my mistake. I was searching the mistake in the wrong matrix, and I was really thinking that it was a bug.